# How do you control nodes in a server farm?

Tags: distributed-computing, cloud-computing, hadoop

I've been reading about hadoop and multi-node setups, and it says in the documentation that you must have a JVM and hadoop software already running on those nodes.

My question is, do people install this software on each of these computers individually? or is there a software solution that automates this process?

I've also read about [KVM switches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch), but I'm not sure whether this is what people usually use in these situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your architecture. On UNIX systems, tools like puppet are really usefull : http://www.puppetlabs.com/ .

You have also deployement tools on windows systems throw groups management.

Then, you'll also need a monitoring tool.

I can't be really precise, as long as you don't give many information to build on.

Comment: What information do you need?